# Creating new table in Supabase client side?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, supabase, supabase-js

I am trying to create a supabase table client side using RPC.

I have setup a function in supabase to be called when RPC is invoked.
Where I pass an table name client side in Next.js with pages router.

```
BEGIN
EXECUTE 'CREATE TABLE ' || custom_table_name || ' (
    id serial PRIMARY KEY,
    name text,
    age integer,
    email text,
    address text
);';
END;
```

From client side i call this function and pass the name.

```
async function createTable(customTableName) {
    try {
      const { data, error } = await supabase.rpc("create_custom_table", {
        custom_table_name: customTableName,
      });

      if (error) {
        console.error("Error: ", error);
      } else {
        console.log("Success:", data);
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error: ", error);
    }
  }
```

I am experiencing the error:

```
code: "42501"
details: null
hint: null
message: "permission denied for schema public"
```

Can someone point me in the right direction on how to make this work.

Comment: Please don't do this as it is bad by design. This would mean that anyone who is using your application client side could call this endpoint and create as many tables as they wish. In relational databases you create the tables prior to using them, it's not the same as NoSQL where you create tables at runtime. You should plan your database structure out well and create the tables necessary from inside the database.

Answer (score 0):

While I agree with a caution against this method, there is an answer to OP's question.

You'll want to add a `SECURITY DEFINER` clause to the function definition before the BEGIN statement.

```sql
SECURITY DEFINER
SET search_path = public
BEGIN
EXECUTE 'CREATE TABLE ' || custom_table_name || ' (
    id serial PRIMARY KEY,
    name text,
    age integer,
    email text,
    address text
);';
END;
```

([More on Security Definer](https://supabase.com/docs/guides/database/functions#security-definer-vs-invoker))

There are a few securities you'd might like to inject here:

- Lock down who can call the RPC function with [Function Privileges](https://supabase.com/docs/guides/database/functions#function-privileges).
- Automated RPC policy creation within the table create function that protects against unwanted actions by the user in this new dynamically created table.